# jQuery Timer does'nt clear interval when the time has passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jQuery countdown timer. It displays the time left until a particular date. Everything works fine when the deadline is not reached. However if the deadline is reached when the page is active, it displays zero in all the field `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`. But when the user loads the page after the deadline is gone, it shows the time in negative. I want to display zero in all sections in this case. I am attaching my code below, please help.

```
var getRemainderTime = function(finishtime) 
{
  var t = Date.parse(finishtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
};

var initializeClock = function(finishtime) 
{

var updateClock = function() 
{
  var t = getRemainderTime(finishtime);

  $("#clockdiv .days").html(t.days);
  $("#clockdiv .hours").html(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
  $("#clockdiv .minutes").html(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
  $("#clockdiv .seconds").html(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2));

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
};

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
};
var deadline = 'October 30 2016 23:59:59 GMT-0400';
```

I thought my `t.total` is not working, but it seems to work fine. Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just add one if condition and return 0 if, the time has already passed.

```js
var getRemainderTime = function(finishtime) 
{
  var t = Date.parse(finishtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  if ( t >= 0  ) {
  
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
    }
  else {
    return {
    'total': 0,
    'days': 0,
    'hours': 0,
    'minutes': 0,
    'seconds': 0
  };
    }
  
};

var initializeClock = function(finishtime) 
{

var updateClock = function() 
{
  var t = getRemainderTime(finishtime);

  $("#clockdiv .days").html(t.days);
  $("#clockdiv .hours").html(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
  $("#clockdiv .minutes").html(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
  $("#clockdiv .seconds").html(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2));

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
};

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
};

document.getElementById('startCountDown').onclick= function () { 
$('#clockdiv').show();  initializeClock(document.getElementById('finishtime').value);
}
```

```css
#finishtime {
  width: 300px;
}
#clockdiv {
  display: none;
}
#startCountDown {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Please set the deadline: <input id="finishtime" type="text" value="September 26 2016 07:48:15 GMT+0530">
<button id="startCountDown"> Start Countdown</button>
</div>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="days"></span> days&nbsp;,
  <span class="hours"></span>hours :&nbsp;
  <span class="minutes"></span>mins :&nbsp;
  <span class="seconds"></span>seconds
</div>
```